# Contar checkbox selecionados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo o problema ao contar os checkbox que estão selecionados, talvez pelo seguinte motivo, tenho um radio que também está selecionado. Sempre que uso o código `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length`
é exido o valor 1, sendo que nenhum checkbox está selecionado. Caso eu selecione apenas um, é exibido o valor 2 e assim sucessivamente. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Dê um `console.log($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'))` verifique quais são os checkbox listados, verifique se não tem nenhum oculto.

Comment: Parece-me bem aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/t9t5cz86/ podes adaptar o jsFiddle com o teu código para ver se encontramos o problema?

Comment: @KaduAmaral fiz isso, e olha oq apareceu: http://postimg.org/image/mdx7uqo1f/. Em nenhum lugar eu encontrei esse código.

Comment: @Sergio meu código é assim: tenho dois radio com as opções PÚBLICO e PRIVADO. Se o usuário clicar em PRIVADO, minha aplicação (em asp.net mvc) busca uma lista de SETORES e eu exibo os setores na tela para o usuário selecionar. Vou tentar colocar o código na url pra vc ver

Comment: @ZackMorgan você usa algum framework? Esse checkbox tem alguma coisa a ver com menu. A causa do número "estar um a mais" é por causa desse checkbox, não tem nada de errado com teu código. Ou tem que remove-lo ou usar outra lógica.

Comment: @KaduAmaral uso vários, pra css, javascript. Essa aplicação está sendo desenvolvida em asp.net mvc. Vou realizar um teste com todos os frameworks no projeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está selecionando todos os checkbox da página, e pode dar conflito com outros grupos de checkbox.

Use uma classe ou atributo para agrupa-los:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="setor" [...]>

$('input.setor[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

Ou

```
<input type="checkbox" data-context="setor" [...]>

$('input[type="checkbox"][data-context="setor"]:checked').length
```

Comment: 100% dessa forma. Vou deixar pra procurar qual plugin fez aquilo. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!!! Abs

Comment: Pelo atributo title tem algo a ver com menu @ZackMorgan.